# How to calculate expectation and variance of smooth function applied to brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion

I applied a smoothing function to a Brownian equation and obtained a stochastic differential equation by using Ito's lemma. The smoothing function is exp(Bt).

How do I get the expected value and variance of this function? Just looking for the required approach rather than a full fledged solution.

Comment: Do you mean $\exp\{B(t)\}$ where $B(t)$ is Brownian motion?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Answer (score 2):

For a Normally distributed random variable, $X$, with mean $\mu$, and variance $V$, the following is true:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \{\exp(\theta X)\} = \exp\left(\theta\mu+\frac{1}{2}\theta^2V\right)
\end{equation}
In your example, conditional upon time $0$, and assuming $B(0)=0$, $B(t)$ is Normally distributed variable with zero mean and variance $t$. Applying this formula with $\mu = 0$, $V=t$ and $\theta=1$, we find:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \{\exp(B(t))\}=\exp \left( \frac{1}{2}t \right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Maybe add somewhere that the question has the case $\theta=1$ for completeness.

Comment: @BobJansen - sure, just added.

Answer (score 0):

As $B(t)$ follows a normal distribution with mean zero and variance $t$, then $\exp\{B(t)\}$ will (by definition) follow  a log-normal distribution with parameters $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=t$. The moments of the log-normal distribution are known.